# MomentJS doesn't load locales

Tags: node.js, momentjs

I am building something with moment and nodejs, but for some reason, the locales don't get loaded. Here is some code:

```
import moment from 'moment'

moment.locale('fr');
console.log(moment.locales());
```

So the console.log only returns the `en` locale so I suppose that the other locales aren't loaded.

However, the documentation says:

> If there is a locale file in moment-root/locale/ named after that key,
>   the first call to moment.locale will load it.

When I check in my `node_modules/moment/locale`, I have indeed a `fr.js` file.

So what am I doing wrong? Am I missing something to load my locales?

Thanks a lot for your help!

EDIT: I am using version `^2.14.1` of momentjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to documentation please make sure that you have imported locale files or used minified file:

```
locale/*.js
```

or

```
min/moment-with-locales.js
```

Comment: Yes, I just found it thank you, the green check is yours

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution, I needed to import the locale into my main js file:

```
import 'moment/locale/fr';
```

Comment: Please note that there is a vite + moment issue (https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/5359#issuecomment-954655191) that requires `import 'moment/dist/locale/fr'` instead as a workaround/fix