# Angular2 + TypeScript + moment.js => locale are not all there (just 'en')

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, momentjs

I am going thru a book tutorial to learn **TypeScript** and **AngularJS 2.0**:(Become_a_Ninja_with_Angular2).

At some point it explains how to make your own Pipe and goes thru an implementation of **moment.js**.

In the folder where my project is located I do in CLI: `npm install moment`
(FYI: The book also tells to do `typings install --save --ambient moment-node`, but that throws an error even if I change `--ambient` by `--global`, also this error happens to not be a problem to use `moment.js` as the rest of the code I describe below runs).

Then, as a result of previous CLI, it creates under my project folder: `[my project folder]\node_modules\moment`

Then in `[my project folder]\main.html`, I have a `<script>` tag with: `

```
<script>
    System.config({
                defaultJSExtensions: true,
                map: {
                    ... [plenty of stuff starting with @angular]..
                    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic':'node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
                    'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs',
                    'moment':'node_modules/moment/moment'
               }
    });

System.import('main');
</script>
```

My custom Pipe looks like this:

```
import { PipeTransform, Pipe } from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from 'moment';
import 'moment/../locale/fr';

@Pipe({name: 'fromNow'})
export class FromNowPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value,args){
         let mydate = moment(new Date(value));


console.log(moment.locales());

         return mydate.fromNow();

    }

}
```

As you can see in my **custom pipe** code, to access the locale `'fr'`, I had to add      `import 'moment/../locale/fr` ([what I found by looking at already existing solution on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39273446/momentjs-doesnt-load-locales/39632698#39632698)). If this tag was not implemented I had access to `'en'` only. Which means that adding other languages will require to add `import 'moment/../locale/[the locale I want available]`.

Anyone has any ideas how to have all the `locale` from the lib moment.js with just the single `import * as moment from 'moment';` statement?

PS: And I added to [My project folder]\app.module.ts:

```
import { FromNowPipe } from './custom_pipes/fromnow.pipe';
...
    @NgModule({
        ...
        declarations: [...,FromNowPipe],
        ...
    })
...
```

And somewhere in one of my component I have:

```
[@Component({
    selector: 'ns-mycomponent',
    template:`
..              <div>{{ '2016/05/01'|fromNow }}</div>..

               `
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround:

Based on what I wrote in the question, in `[my project folder]\main.html`:

```
 System.config({
            defaultJSExtensions: true,
            map: {
                ... 
           }
});
```

I substitued: `'moment':'node_modules/moment/moment'` with `'moment':'node_modules/moment/min/moment-with-locales.min.js'`

In my Pipe file I just kept: `import * as moment from 'moment';`at the beginning of the file and it works: **all languages are available**.